# How to write the program to get these type of output?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile

if the data is coming dynamically in footer which contain swipe in it .
   through ajax calling i m doing the coding it is xml parsing with GET method is used

In Html:-

```
   <div data-role="page" id="page1">
         <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
              <div id="wrapper">
              <div id="image1"></div>
              <div class="menu" id="menu_button1"></div>
         </div> 
  </div>
```

In jquery:-

```
 function callMenuConnection() {  
        $.support.cors = true;
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "one.html",
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: "",
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
                crossDomain:true,
                success: processSuccess,
                error: processError
            }); 
      }
```

i need these output:-

[image]

Comment: first you need to learn the basics of html, css

Comment: plz help me out wid code